# Setting up a controller property after the model hook

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I need to set a controller property after the `model` hook. I can think of two ways to do this:

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('user', 1);
},

afterModel(model, transition) {
  model.get('profile').then(profile => {
    this.set('profile', profile);
  });
},

setupController(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model);
  controller.set('profile', this.get('profile'));
},
```

The other approach. i.e. skip `setupController`:

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('user', 1);
},

afterModel(model, transition) {
  model.get('profile').then(profile => {
    this.controller.set('profile', profile);
  });
},
```

Both seem to work.

Are there any added advantages / disadvantages with either approach? Clearly, the latter is shorter. But does it feel "clean" to set the controller property in an `afterModel` hook?

**EDIT**: the relationship/association between `user` and `profile` is `async`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As another poster pointed out, you can access `model.profile`, but that won't work from code if `profile` is an async association:

```
// models/user.js
profile: belongsTo('profile', { async: true })
```

The reason is that `model.profile` will return a promise rather than a value. To solve that, you can use the `afterModel` hook as you suggested, but all you need is

```
afterModel(model, transition) {
  return model.get('profile');
},
```

That will issue the async call and pause the transition until it is completed, at which point the `profile` may be accessed as `model.profile` as usual. If for some reason you really want to access the profile as a controller property to avoid having to prefix it with `model.`, just define an alias in your controller:

```
profile: Ember.computed.alias('model.profile')
```

If there is more than one such property, then the following should do the job:

```
return Ember.RSVP.Promise.hash(this.getProperties('profile', ...));
```

You could also implement this right in the `model` hook, although it's a bit less readable:

```
model() {
  return this.store.findRecord('user', 1) .
    then(user => user.get('profile') . 
      then(() => user)
    );
}
```

What this says is, find the user, and then when found get his profile (which will cause the async request to fire), then when that is found return the user from the promise, so it is correctly set into `model`.

Comment: Yeap, relationships are async. Simply doing `model.get('profile')` in the `afterModel` hook will still return a promise. A `then` clause is required. Or did I miss something?

Comment: `model.get('profile')` will issue the async request, and return a promise telling the transition machinery to wait until it's complete. When it is complete, `model.profile` will automatically be resolved so that future references to it will return the value. `model.profile` is a kind of hybrid promise+value object.

Comment: Oh interesting. Just tried this out and I see how that works now. Im curious. This will only work if the `afterModel` hook is returning one object. What if the `afterModel` hook needs to return more than one. i.e. `model.get('profile')`, and `model.get('somethingElse')`. Should I then use `this.controller.set` instead?

Comment: You could `return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all([this.get('profile'), ...]);`.Or possibly `return Ember.RSVP.Promise.hash(this.getProperties('profile', ...));`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any of those code, because controller has access to model via `this.model`. In any controller's method you can just call `this.get('model.profile')`. In template you may use `{{model.profile}}`.

Comment: Calling `this.get('model.profile')` will not do what you expect if `profile` is an async association.